# Oracle RAC: Configure instance to depend on VIP

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-rac

In previous version of Oracle RAC with Oracle clusterware, before 10.0.1 I believe, an instance was dependent on a VIP resource. Once a vip was failed or relocated, the Instance would be stopped.
In later versiond, this coupling was broken, as I understand it, by costumer requests.

Since an instance is not a regular resource in the CRS cluster, and can not be configured with crs_profile, how can I create a dependency between an Instance and it's VIP?

Comment: I'm wondering what is the reason behind this? Are you sure you don't misunderstand the relations between VIP and listener and between the listener and the instance?

Comment: The reasoning was a service (Streams apply) that was running on an instance, and would not move to the other instance on vip failure. This would cause synchronization problems with every network problem

Comment: What was preventing the secondary listener to serve this service?

Comment: I am not a DBA, but I was told it has something to do with an apply queue running in the specific instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!
The trick is to re-register the instance resource. As root:

```
crs_stat -p ora.db.instance1.inst > /tmp/ora.db.instance1.inst.cap
```

Edit /tmp/ora.db.instance1.inst.cap and add the vip resource to REQUIRED_RESOURCES

Run:

```
crs_register ora.db.instance1.inst -d /tmp -u
```

the "-u", I'm guessing is update, does the magic. After that you need to re set permission (or maybe run the whole thing as "oracle" user)

```
crs_setperm ora.db.instance1.inst -o oracle
crs_setperm ora.db.instance1.inst -g dba
crs_setperm ora.db.instance1.inst -u pgrp:dba:rwx
```

That's it. Run a

```
crs_stat -p crs_stat -p ora.db.instance1.inst
```

to make sure the changes have been saved and restart the instance

This is relevent to 10.2.0.4